# Draw horizontal lines in Chart.js 2.0

Tags: chart.js, chart.js2

Can you help me how to extend Chart.js v2.0. I need to draw some horizontal lines in the charts, something similar to: http://jsfiddle.net/vsh6tcfd/3/

```
var originalLineDraw = Chart.controllers.bar.prototype.draw;

Chart.helpers.extend(Chart.controllers.bar.prototype, {
  draw: function() {
    originalLineDraw.apply(this, arguments);

    var chart = this.chart;
    var ctx = chart.chart.ctx;

    var index = chart.config.data.lineAtIndex;
    if (index) {
      var xaxis = chart.scales['x-axis-0'];
      var yaxis = chart.scales['y-axis-0'];

      ctx.save();
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(xaxis.getPixelForValue(undefined, index), yaxis.left);
      ctx.strokeStyle = '#ff0000';
      ctx.lineTo(xaxis.getPixelForValue(undefined, index), yaxis.right);
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.restore();
    }
  }
});

var config = {
    type: type,
    data:  jQuery.extend(true, {}, data),
    options: this.chartdata.options,
    lineAtIndex: 2
};

new Chart(ctx, config);
```

Comment: In the fiddle provided, you actually *do* draw horizontal lines, don`t you? What exactly do you want to change?

Comment: The provided fiddle used Chart.js v1 but i am using v2. That code is not working on v2.

Comment: Sorry, did not notice that...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## Options

With chart.js you have 2 options.

1. You could create a mix chart types ([Example Here](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/mixed.html)). This would allow you to add a line charts to create your lines.
2. You could create a plugin (See Example Below).

Option 2 would be the one I recommend as it allows you to have more control over the appearance of the lines.

## The Fix

[demo of the plugin](http://jsfiddle.net/Lgtzcr7v/2/)

Chart.js now [supports plugins](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#advanced-usage-creating-plugins). This allows you to add any features you want to your charts!

To create a plugin you will need to run code after an event has occurred and modify the chart/canvas as needed.
The following code should give you a good starting point:

```
var horizonalLinePlugin = {
  afterDraw: function(chartInstance) {
    var yValue;
    var yScale = chartInstance.scales["y-axis-0"];
    var canvas = chartInstance.chart;
    var ctx = canvas.ctx;
    var index;
    var line;
    var style;

    if (chartInstance.options.horizontalLine) {
      for (index = 0; index < chartInstance.options.horizontalLine.length; index++) {
        line = chartInstance.options.horizontalLine[index];

        if (!line.style) {
          style = "rgba(169,169,169, .6)";
        } else {
          style = line.style;
        }

        if (line.y) {
          yValue = yScale.getPixelForValue(line.y);
        } else {
          yValue = 0;
        }

        ctx.lineWidth = 3;

        if (yValue) {
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.moveTo(0, yValue);
          ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, yValue);
          ctx.strokeStyle = style;
          ctx.stroke();
        }

        if (line.text) {
          ctx.fillStyle = style;
          ctx.fillText(line.text, 0, yValue + ctx.lineWidth);
        }
      }
      return;
    }
  }
};
Chart.pluginService.register(horizonalLinePlugin);
```

Comment: If you remove the `ctx.font = "20px Georgia";` it looks like chart.js will use the same font and font size as the chart. I think that looks better overall and would recommend removing it.

Comment: Thanks for the code! Works a treat *after* adding `var yValue;` in ECMA6 ;-) Had me flustered for a while with a `yValue is undefined` error in the console.

Comment: Good catch @StanSmulders. I updated my answer with the correction.

Comment: You might want to consider changing your code to `ctx.moveTo(chartInstance.chartArea.left, yValue);` and `ctx.lineTo(chartInstance.chartArea.right, yValue);` which will draw the line on the graph only and not the entire canvas.

Comment: Is it possible to draw a dash line?

Comment: Yes. Use ctx.setLineDash([3, 5]);/*dashes are 3px and spaces are 5px*/. [Demo use. Change added on line 33](http://jsfiddle.net/Lgtzcr7v/112/)